# CSS animation on after element doesn't appear to do anything?

Tags: html, css

I believe it's possible to add css to pseudo elements in CSS even though it is a working draft currently.

However, upon trying in the latest version of Chrome I can't seem to get it working.

I want the :after element on my header to transition in instead of looking so blocky.

I have added the transition to my after element but it's still the same, have I specified the CSS as below;

```
#main-header:after {
height: 95px;
content: " ";
width: 100%;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
background: url(http://stbenedicts.justinternetdns.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/waves-test-1.png) top center;
z-index: 1;
top: 144px;
}

#main-header.et-fixed-header:after {
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s, color 0.4s, transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.4s, color 0.4s, transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color 0.4s, color 0.4s, transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
   top: 54px;
}
```

So that when scrolled, the after element should ease in and not be one solid movement.

Any advice?

EDIT: http://stbenedicts.justinternetdns.co.uk/ <- playground

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `transition` properties (`-webkit-transition`, `-moz-transition`, `transition`) on the base class (`#main-header:after`).

```
#main-header:after {
    height: 95px;
    content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background: url(http://stbenedicts.justinternetdns.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/waves-test-1.png) top center;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 144px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s, color 0.4s, transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s, color 0.4s, transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s, color 0.4s, transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

#main-header.et-fixed-header:after {
   top: 54px;
}
```

By defining the transition on the base class the browser knows to *transition* when the modified condition — the addition, presumably, of `et-fixed-header` in your example — occurs. Otherwise, it only *applies the `transition` properties* to the class when that condition is present; meaning that you would only see the transition if/when that modifier is removed. [This article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/) does a far better job of explaining it.

**EDIT:** I hadn't noticed you were only specifying `background-color` for your `transition` property. In addition to moving the `transition` properties to the base class, you'll have to either add the other properties (the syntax is explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions#Multiple_animated_properties_example), or broadly transition `all` properties

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the assumption that the transition(s) are supposed to take place when the `.et-fixed-header` is added.

But what are you transitioning?

```
transition: 
background-color 0.4s, 
color 0.4s, 
transform 0.4s, 
opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
```

But *from* what *to* what?

You aren't setting initial values for those properties or end values.

The only thing you are changing (except the background, kinda) is the `top` value and you aren't transitioning that at all.

So you would need to set actual values on your `#main-header` rule to start with and new **different** values on your `#main-header.et-fixed-header` rule

Comment: I've added a link above, basically I'm trying to transition the after effect so it moves up when the header resizes, without looking jerky

Comment: Links aren't useful here...you'd need to make a [mcve] but even so, I think I've covered the problem. You aren't actually transitioning values,